# how to change language in openERP(odoo 8)

Tags: odoo

I want to change the language of openERP's latest version Odoo 8,

some one give me suggestion and I am also googling about this problem and I found that change into the preferences but that menu also I not locate,

Please give me a suggestion for how to do that and if any query related questions please comment me....)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the user on right top you will see preferences menu.

In preferences menu change language and then reload page if does not work logout of system and login again.

Comment: There is only the English language for me.

Comment: u have to add other languages by using Load Translation in Settings Menu

Answer (score 0):

- Module setting -> Menu Translation -> Load a Translation (choose your language)

Then

- Click on the user on right top you will see preferences menu  -> change your language